# Background color for drawing CIImage

Tags: ios, core-image, glkit

I use some of `CIFilter`s to do some image processing. I've found `UIImageView` too slow to display output image in real-time. I've followed [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH3-SW19) and built `GLKView`. Now the performance is perfect, but image is rendered in black rect when rotated.

[image]

How to set that color to background (green in this case) or transparent?

Here is drawing code snippet. I'm not familiar with graphics domain at all.

```
private class ImageView: GLKView {

    override init!(frame: CGRect, context: EAGLContext!) { // Called with `.OpenGLES3` context.
        ciContext = CIContext(EAGLContext: context, options: [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()])
        super.init(frame: frame, context: context)    
    }

    private let ciContext: CIContext

    private var image: CIImage? {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    private override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        // Clear with `glClear`... Here is set color from `backgroundColor` (green) and cleared with it.

        if image != nil {                
            ciContext.drawImage(image!, inRect: { /* returned computed rect */ }(), fromRect: image!.extent())
        }
    }

    private override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting a blend mode?

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
```

Check this [link](http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php) to show the visual effects of the blend mode

If you are setting a blend mode can you show more of what is going on in the drawRect method?

Comment: I'm doing something similar and still having issues after adding the above.  I'm using a CIAffineTransform filter to rotate a CIImage and getting the black background. My CIContext is created from an EAGLContext, and I'm drawing the final image into a CVPixelBuffer that's eventually rendered as a video frame. I've added the above OpenGL calls, but the area outside of the rotated image is still black. Any thoughts as to other settings I might need to make the background transparent? Thanks!